# Why script isn't downloaded when loading html via Ajax call

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

I write in MVC.

I have UserControl that has inside **only this**

**UPDATED**

```
<div id="login-container">
    <div id="login">
        <script src="/Scripts/shared/Site.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

When I load this control through Ajax call(I return View("UserControl")), so the script isn't downloaded. The only way to fix it is to write

```
$.getScript("Scripts/shared/Site.js")
```

after

```
$("#container").html(UserControlHtml)
```

I realize that this happens only when I load UserControl through Ajax call, but I don't understand why.
Can someone explain what is going on behind the scene? I want to understand why loading html with script inside it doesn't downloads the script

Thank you

Comment: i guess we'll take that as a 'no' then :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may find that your issue is inside the usercontrol. you should change the following line:

```
<script src="/Scripts/shared/Site.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to:

```
<script src="<%=Url.Content('~/Scripts/shared/Site.js')%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

that's my guess anyway..

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't work because this is not the problem. The problem because this peace of html is loaded through ajax. BUT I want to understand why

Comment: user, it will depend on the datatype requested via ajax as well. i.e. have a look at the answer on this question for clues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203762/when-loading-an-html-page-via-ajax-will-script-tags-be-loaded/2203816#2203816