# why is my javascript in an called ajax doesn't work? with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

ok lets say im doing something like

http://localhost/ajax/social/pull/facebookstatus

on my `/ajax/social/pull/facebookstatus` there is a script something like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
      google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table, 
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
      function drawChart() {

      // Create our data table.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
```

back to the problem im trying to call ( lets say at http://localhost/myprofile )

```
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",                    // Using the POST method  
        url: "/ajax/social/pull/facebookstatus",      // The file to call  
        data: myfbdata, 
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
        $('#ajax-placeputfb').hide().fadeIn(3000).html(data);
        }  
    });
```

the script on `/ajax/social/pull/facebookstatus` doesnt work when its loaded on `http://localhost/myprofile`

is there a problem?

Thanks

Adam Ramadhan

Comment: I couldn't connect to your localhost :)

Comment: its a `lets say` dude :D , anyway cant we load javascript on a javascipt ajax call?

Comment: well it does load, but my JavaScript that shows the graph doent show up, it shows everything else except that.

Comment: is your drawChart() function getting called?

Comment: what's the HTTP response from the server when your AJAX call is made? Is there a HTTP response at all?

Comment: yes but it stop there when im trying to see the error. i think thats the problem, @cris no there no response, but there is a ajax post.

Comment: heres the details http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5984602/Untitled.png

Comment: its stops then go to the script tab.

Answer (score 0):

is this a related question? [When loading an html page via ajax, will script tags be loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203762/when-loading-an-html-page-via-ajax-will-script-tags-be-loaded)

A similar issue I had when the lib was not included in the `<head>`

Maybe you can try including this in the `<head>` tag of your main document

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>`

Comment: yes im aware of that im useing dataType: 'html'.. edit* im trying to get a part ( just a div like {ajaxhere} `<div id="facebookstatus">blabla</div><div id="facebook-graph"></div>` ) into a page.

Comment: See if the var named google is set. You can call `console.debug(google);` inside the <script> and see if firebug console shows it.

Comment: yes, that is the issue you see. Did you try following my answer to include that library in the <head> tag?

Comment: edit* it somehow redirect me to a blank page, and it says, waiting for google, then blank out. so its just google? becouse it work fine when i open it from `/ajax/social/pull/facebookstatus`