# AJAX: why isn't my javascript loading with the content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is my first time using AJAX. I'm trying to load one of my pages when a link is clicked (I know I can just do `<a href="something.html">` but I am doing it just for the sake of using AJAX, and ran into an issue where my page loads but the javascript of the page doesn't. Is this a normal AJAX consequence? I'm guessing it has to do with `dataType: html`? Here's my code:

```
function getContent(filename) {
    $.ajax({
        url: filename,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "html",
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('html').html('<img src="../images/loading.gif">');
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
            if (filename == "second.html") {
                setTimeout(function (){
                    $('html').html(data);
                }, 2000);
            } else {
                $('html').html(data);
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('html').html(textStatus);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: if you load a full page, just update `location`.

Comment: You can find the answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203762/when-loading-an-html-page-via-ajax-will-script-tags-be-loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check chrome's network monitor? First off, does anything get a 404? Is the file literally second.html? If so then there shouldn't be path issues. Next what is the "response" that appears for that item? Does that response look ok?

Next, why don't you try moving the JS from head into the body for the second page? JS should always be right before the closing body tag for performance reasons. Also, there may be an issue with JS being in head and it not getting executed for that reason.

You should be able to load anything on your domain without any issues via AJAX, but there are path issues to watch out for.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the ajax page is only returning rendered content, but does not run like a normal page would. You can use PHP on the ajax page for example, the server renders it and then sends it through, because PHP is pre-render, javascript runs after the page is rendered, as far as I know.

Comment: so does that mean I should only be loading images and text with AJAX?