# html <head> not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, html, utf-8, xmlhttprequest

I have the following problem:

I have loaded a page using a basic xmlhttp request like this:

```
xmlhttp = getXMLHTTP();

xmlhttp.open("POST",link,true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("principal").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}   

xmlhttp.send();
```

Where **link** is the source of the file that I want to call dynamically and **principal** is the div where I want it to be loaded. This does not seem to be the main error of my problem (which I will explain below) since I have tested it with many pages.

My problem now remains on the fact that I want to have a "popup" box which is in the page loaded with xmlhttp that will show the terms and conditions of my webpage, and the **head** html tag is not being parsed since the **charset UTF-8** is not respected: the accents and special characters appear with a **?** symbol instead of the right one.

I load this popup with the following PHP code:

```
<?php include_once('../../info/terms_and_conds.html'); ?>
```

And the HTML code which is inside this file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Terms and Conditions</title>
</head>
<body>

This is a test á  é  í  ó  ú   ñ   ç 

</body>
</html>
```

Finally, the output is the following one:

```
This is a test � � � � � � �
```

Note: I would have wanted to post a picture of it, but I don't have enough reputation. Sorry for the inconveniences

I also have to tell that all accents and special characters are displayed properly in the page loaded with the xmlhttp Request. 
Could it be the **include_once()** function the one that is producing this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try with jQuery AJAX and this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203762/when-loading-an-html-page-via-ajax-will-script-tags-be-loaded

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I had already visited this post and I also think that the problem is not in the xmlhttp Request since I have not experienced any problem with it untill now. My last option would be to use jQuery AJAX instead of it but I really don't think this would solve my problem.

Comment: if none of the answers solved the issue, then another thing to check is if **all** your files are UTF-8 encoded as the file format. 9 times out of 10, that's what the problem is.  If you don't know how to check that, let  me know. use the @ symbol followed by my name to do that.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I don't really know how to do it, would you be so kind to explain it to me? Thank you in advance

Comment: If you have a code "editor", check the file's encoding. If you don't have one, find Notepad++ on the web, download it and then check it in there. The file's encoding will be shown under "Encoding" in the dropdown menu. Careful though, there are 2 types, UTF-8 with and without BOM.

Comment: so @Alberto where are we with this; making any progress?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Perfect!! Your advice has completely solved my problem! Apparently I was using a Windows' type encoding. I have changed it to UTF-8 and now it works perfectly. Thank you very much dude!

Comment: By the way, how could I do it to state that your advice has been my solution in this page? @Fred-ii-

Comment: you're welcome @Alberto I'm glad it got resolved. I will post my answer below if you wish to accept it to close the question and mark it as solved.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Perfect! Do it and I will close the question

Comment: @Alberto Great, *cheers*

Comment: Cheers @Fred-ii- and thank you for your rapid response !

Comment: You're very much welcome @Alberto I was glad to have been of help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that your files are not saved as/encoded as UTF-8.

As stated in comments, using a code editor (Notepad++ was suggested) open the file(s) and check its encoding.

If it isn't UTF-8, convert it to that, then save the file(s).

Reference:

- https://notepad-plus-plus.org/ - Notepad++ (for Windows)

*Although there are other code editors that will do the same operation.*

---

Footnotes:

If you have any issues later on and getting an headers already sent... warning, then you will need to encode as UTF-8 without BOM.

A BOM (a.k.a. byte order mark) counts as output (before header).

Here is more on the subject:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Answer (score 2):

Probably your webserver is sending different charset headers than you specified in your `<meta/>` tag. Try to specify content type header explicitly in PHP file.

```
<?php 
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    include_once('../../info/terms_and_conds.html'); 
?>
```

Comment: My guess exactly. The server file is in ASCII. While the content loaded is UTF8. Force the page to be UTF8 by setting the content header.

Comment: I have just done it and it still does not work. What's more, I have tried to apply the sentence 

    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

in the same file but it does not help either..

Answer (score 1):

This is really just due to encoding - 
If you change that meta-tag that has "UTF-8" in it to the following:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset= ISO-8859-1" />
```

Then everything should appear as it is supposed to.