# flexslider doesn't work within ajax Magnific popup

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, flexslider, magnific-popup

I'm trying to load flexslider within magnific popup, but for some reason the script inside the popup doesn't work.

Magnific pop up is load with wordpress function `wp_enqueue_script()`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        $('.ajax-popup-link').magnificPopup({
            type:'ajax',
            midClick: true,
            overflowY: "scroll",
            alignTop: false,
        });
});
```

Then, by clikcing a button the pop up opens this file:

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="popup-container">

    <?php
    // Loop start
    if( have_posts() ):

      while( have_posts() ) : the_post();

        get_template_part( 'agency', 'popup' );

      endwhile;

    else :

      echo "no agencies found";

    endif;
    ?>



  </div><!--.popup-container-->

</div> <!--.container -->
```

Inside agency-popup.php:

```
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="slide1.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="slide2.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="slide3.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="slide4.jpg" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script>

 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {   
    $(window).load(function() {
           $('.flexslider').flexslider({
              animation: "slide"
          });
     });
  });

</script>
```

But the jquery doesn't load.. I've tried to add it inside the page where the button is, and inside the `<head></head>` section, in both case it doesn't work either.
NOTE: I've loaded flexslider with `wp_enqueue_script()` and checked that it enqueued, and it did.

Comment: Inserting script via AJAX will not run it - so, after the raising of popup you need to enable flexslider. Another solution would be to raise an iframe.

Comment: Where should I put it then?

Comment: Check the [open event](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#api) in Docs.

Comment: Tried to do the fowlloing which still doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/4wmer1c2/3/. Much appreciate your help m8..

Answer (score 0):

You should enable the flexslider after raising the popup:

```
$('.ajax-popup-link').magnificPopup({
    type:'ajax',
    midClick: true,
    overflowY: "scroll",
    alignTop: false,
    callbacks: {
        open: function() {
            $('.mfp-content .flexslider').flexslider({
                animation: "slide"
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Explanation: Inserting script via AJAX will not run it. But, as specified [in answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203762/when-loading-an-html-page-via-ajax-will-script-tags-be-loaded), if you use jQuery `dataType: html`, than it would be evaluated.

Comment: So I need to use `dataType: html` inside `magnificPopup` function, and insert the script in the original file (as I did the first time, without the callback)?

Comment: `dataType` is for jQuery `ajax` method, really don't know what magnificPopup use in this case, would have to go through the source code.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who might tackle this thread, I was manage to solve this by using this callback:

```
callbacks: {            
    ajaxContentAdded: function() {
            $('#carousel').flexslider({
                animation: 'slide',
                direction: 'vertical',
                controlNav: false,
                animationLoop: true,
                slideshow: false,
                itemWidth: 143,
                itemMargin: 2,
                asNavFor: '#slider'
            });
            $('#slider').flexslider({
                animation: 'slide',
                controlNav: false,
                animationLoop: false,
                slideshow: false,
                sync: '#carousel'
            });
        }
}
```